# How do I get theme to apply for Hugo/Netlify website?

Tags: r, markdown, hugo, blogdown

Using the [hugo-geo theme](https://github.com/alexurquhart/hugo-geo) and RStudio, I've built a [website](https://k22daugherty.netlify.com/) on Netlify.  My code is on GitHub (https://github.com/kathryn2/Website).

**Issue I'm having:**  The initial page works great. Hyperlinks on left pane all work as intended.  When selecting individual posts from the left pane (e.g., https://k22daugherty.netlify.com/post/how-heavily-armed-is-your-state/), formatting totally craps out.  It's as if there's no theme and the site doesn't know what to do.  I tried seeing if it's a lack of knitting the markdown pages and when I do that I get errors that the images cannot be found. This is my first stab with Rmarkdown (though I'm used to JupyterNotebook with Python), so any obvious fixes are worth mentioning.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: What is the exact error message? Can you put a rmarkdown chunk where this error happens?

Comment: It the lack of knitting what's causing the theme to not carry over?  The pictures are showing up, so my perceived issue is theming inconsistency.

Comment: Here's the output I get:
processing file: 2016-12-17-how-heavily-armed-is-your-state.Rmd
  |.................................................................| 100%
  ordinary text without R code

Comment: output file: 2016-12-17-how-heavily-armed-is-your-state.knit.md

/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/pandoc/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS 2016-12-17-how-heavily-armed-is-your-state.utf8.md --to html4 --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output 2016-12-17-how-heavily-armed-is-your-state.html --smart --email-obfuscation none --self-contained --standalone --section-divs --template

Comment: /Users/kathryn_daugherty/Library/R/3.5/library/rmarkdown/rmd/h/default.html --no-highlight --variable highlightjs=1 --variable 'theme:bootstrap' --include-in-header /var/folders/gb/t5w_mwv15mv1rqgt0c4n0m500000gn/T//Rtmpg23VDM/rmarkdown-str1e676a4a20ac.html --mathjax --variable 'mathjax-url:https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML' 
pandoc: Could not fetch /post/2016-12-17-how-heavily-armed-is-your-state_files/Firearms_Data_KAD.png

Comment: /post/2016-12-17-how-heavily-armed-is-your-state_files/Firearms_Data_KAD.png: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 67
Execution halted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

modify [this file](https://github.com/kathryn2/Website/blob/master/public/post/how-heavily-armed-is-your-state/index.html)in the line 23 from

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/style.css">
```

If it does not work please notice that your github repository should be the **public** folder instead of the whole folder where you create your R project and where you are using blogdown.

Comment: I made this edit, but with a backslash before public.  Did this to two index files:  (1) https://github.com/kathryn2/Website/blob/master/public/post/index.html
(2) https://github.com/kathryn2/Website/blob/master/public/post/how-heavily-armed-is-your-state/index.html

Issue persists.

Also, what do you mean by github repo should...?  Can you please clarify which folders/files are in the wrong folder(s)?  I'm not quite sure how to fix...

Comment: When you use blogdown and Hugo (I mean, when using the serve function), many folders and files get automatically created. But the folder **public** is where your website is. From your [github repository](https://github.com/kathryn2/Website) upload only the files within the **public** folder. Try creating a new repository with all the files within **public** (but do not upload the folder, you need the files). You have to upload [all this](https://github.com/kathryn2/Website/tree/master/public) The enable the gh-page branch and see if now content is displayed as expected.

Comment: I got it to work.  Not fully sure how, but your advice did help greatly.  Thanks!!!